# npm info [pkg] succeeds but yarn info [pkg] fails - No package matched your request

Tags: json, npm, yarnpkg, yarn-v2

I'm using yarn 3 (yarn berry)..

NPM:

```
npm info lincd-jsonld
```

works

This URL works: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/lincd-jsonld

so the package exists in the yarn registry..

But

```
yarn info lincd-jsonld
```

gives me

```
Usage Error: No package matched your request
```

Why?